# Grouping expressions by their $O(..)$ rate of growth around 0

Tags: probability-or-statistics, algebraic-manipulation

Given a list of expressions like $3 x^2,\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{\pi },\frac{9 x^3}{2},x,$, how could I group them based on their rates of growth around 0?

IE, $2x$ and $3x$ are both $O(x)$, while $x^2$ is $O(x^2)$.

Code below generates 25 expressions I'm trying to group in this way:

```
pairs = {
   {"Kumaraswamy", KumaraswamyDistribution[2, 3]},
   {"Weihbul", WeibullDistribution[1/2, 2]},
   {"ArcSin", ArcSinDistribution[]},
   {"Bates", BatesDistribution[3]},
   {"Uniform", UniformDistribution[]},
   {"Pareto", ParetoDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"Logistic", LogisticDistribution[]},
   {"Extreme Value", ExtremeValueDistribution[]},
   {"Frechet", FrechetDistribution[2, 1, 0]},
   {"Erlang", ErlangDistribution[3, 2]},
   {"Gamma", GammaDistribution[2, 3]},
   {"InverseGamma", InverseGammaDistribution[2, 3]},
   {"Gumbel", GumbelDistribution[0, 1]},
   {"Beta", BetaDistribution[1/2, 1]},
   {"Marchenko-Pastur", MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1]},
   {"Semicircle", WignerSemicircleDistribution[1]},
   {"LogNormal", LogNormalDistribution[0, 1]},
   {"Cauchy", CauchyDistribution[]},
   {"Pareto", ParetoDistribution[1, 2]},
   {"Normal", NormalDistribution[]},
   {"Student-T", StudentTDistribution[1]},
   {"ChiSquared", ChiSquareDistribution[1]},
   {"Chi", ChiDistribution[1]},
   {"Exponential", ExponentialDistribution[1]},
   {"Inverse Normal", InverseGaussianDistribution[2, 1]}
   };
trunc[dist_] := TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, dist];

getGrowth[dist_] := 
  Assuming[0 < x < 1/1000, Asymptotic[Refine@CDF[dist, x], x -> 0]];
getGrowth[trunc@Last@#] & /@ pairs
```

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-distribution-growth.nb)

Motivation: getting a sense of asymptotics of Laplace transform for various random variables, which can be [inferred from behavior of their CDF around 0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619832/relationship-between-cdf-and-mgf)

Comment: "Rate of growth" generally means the value of the first derivative. I think you mean "order of growth"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Group`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Group.html) and [`AsymptoticEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticEqual.html).

```
exprs = getGrowth[trunc@Last@#] & /@ pairs;
Gather[exprs, AsymptoticEqual[#1, #2, x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] &]
(* {
 {3 x^2, x^2/18, E^(-((-2 + x)^2/(8 x))) Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x] - x^2/16 - (E x^2)/16}, 
 {Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2], (2 Sqrt[x])/π, Sqrt[x], (2 Sqrt[x])/π, Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x]}, 
 {(9 x^3)/2, (4 x^3)/3}, 
 {x, x/2, x/(-1 + E), x, (4 x)/π, (2 x)/π, Sqrt[2/π] x, (2 x)/π, Sqrt[2/π] x, x}, 
 {0, 0}, 
 {E^(-(1/x^2))}, 
 {(3 E^(-3/x))/x}, 
 {-(E^(-(1/2) Log[x]^2)/(Sqrt[2 π] Log[x]))}
} *)
```

Comment: A deficiency: groups `...,{x, x/2, x/(-1 + E), x, (4 x)/π, (2 x)/π, Sqrt[2/π] x, (2 x)/π, Sqrt[2/π] x, x}, 
 {0, 0}, 
 {E^(-(1/x^2))},...` are not ordered by the growth at the origin.

Comment: @user64494, first, the language to be used on StackExchange is English, so please refrain from (unnecessary) comments in other languages. Second, the OP says nothing about the ordering, just grouping the expressions.

Comment: (i) There were Chinese signs at this forum without any remarks. (ii) There are Internet translators.

Comment: @user64494 [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: @Choster. Thank you for the link. I clearly understand that English is Latin of nowadays. I don't know such an expression as " Если бы губы Никанора Ивановича да приставить к носу Ивана Кузьмича..." in English.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces a list

```
{3 x^2, Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2], (2 Sqrt[x])/π, (9 x^3)/2, x, 0, x/2, x/(-1 + E),
E^(-(1/x^2)), (4 x^3)/3, x^2/18, (3 E^(-3/x))/x, x, Sqrt[x], (2 Sqrt[x])/π, 
(4 x)/π, -(E^(-(1/2) Log[x]^2)/(Sqrt[2 π] Log[x])), ( 2 x)/π, 0,
 Sqrt[2/π] x, (2 x)/π, Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x], Sqrt[2/π] x, x, 
 E^(-((-2 + x)^2/(8 x))) Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x] - x^2/16 - (E x^2)/16}
```

> `{3 x^2, Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2], (2 Sqrt[x])/π, (9 x^3)/2, x, 0, x/2, x/(-1 + E), E^(-(1/x^2)), (4 x^3)/3, x^2/18, (3 E^(-3/x))/x, x, Sqrt[x], (2 Sqrt[x])/π,  (4 x)/π, -(E^(-(1/2) Log[x]^2)/(Sqrt[2 π] Log[x])), ( 2 x)/π, 0, Sqrt[2/π] x, (2 x)/π, Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x], Sqrt[2/π] x, x,  E^(-((-2 + x)^2/(8 x))) Sqrt[2/π] Sqrt[x] - x^2/16 - (E x^2)/16}`

Now

```
Sort[%, AsymptoticLess[#1, #2, x -> 0,Direction->"FromAbove"] &]
```

> `{0, 0, E^(-(1/x^2)), ( 3 E^(-3/x))/x, -(E^(-(1/2) Log[x]^2)/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Log[x])), ( 4 x^3)/3, (9 x^3)/2,  E^(-((-2 + x)^2/(8 x))) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[x] - x^2/16 - (E x^2)/ 16, x^2/18, 3 x^2, x, Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] x, (2 x)/\[Pi],  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] x, (2 x)/\[Pi], (4 x)/\[Pi], x, x/(-1 + E), x/2, x,  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[x], (2 Sqrt[x])/\[Pi], Sqrt[x], ( 2 Sqrt[x])/\[Pi], Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2]}`

does the job.

Edit. `Direction->"FromAbove"` is added to produce the more accurate result. Thanks to @Domen.

Comment: Now applying `Gather[%, AsymptoticEqual[#1, #2, x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] &]` , one obtains `{{0, 0}, {E^(-(1/x^2))}, {-(E^(-(1/2) Log[x]^2)/(
   Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Log[x]))}, {E^(-((-2 + x)^2/(8 x))) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]
     Sqrt[x] - x^2/16 - (E x^2)/16, x^2/18, 3 x^2}, {x, 
  Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] x, (2 x)/\[Pi], Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] x, (2 x)/\[Pi], (
  4 x)/\[Pi], x, x/(-1 + E), x/2, x}, {Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sqrt[x], (
  2 Sqrt[x])/\[Pi], Sqrt[x], (2 Sqrt[x])/\[Pi], Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2]}, {(
  3 E^(-3/x))/x}, {(4 x^3)/3, (9 x^3)/2}}`. which is not correct.